# Microsoft Teams | Expand Tab using JS

Tags: microsoft-teams

Hi my organisation has been creating an app on microsoft teams that allows users to view glpi website inside of a teams tab. The app in itself is just a shortcut to make it easier for the users to navigate through teams.
We need to use an html file with java script in it so that the app redirects to the website in a tab as microsoft teams doesn't allow us to show external website inside of a teams app.
My question is the following : Is it possible that when as a user i click the app button and the redirection to the website tab happens, that this tab automatically expands so that it take all the space inside the teams client. I want it to trigger the "expand the tab" option. (I accept whatever solution you may find because i haven't been able to find something relevant)

This was my first post i thank you for you time and effort and for reading me, have a nice one.
(I tried my best to review this before posting but i'm not sure that i haven't made any mistakes).

I have tried a bunch of useless edits...

Comment: Can't you just use the built-in "Website" app to show an external website? I.e. click "New Tab", then look for "website" app.

Comment: I think i explained it wrong when i said team App. I meant an app that we created with appstudio and plublished in the store that can be pinned to the left toolbar and used as  shortcut to the concerned tab.

Comment: Do you want to just pin the sideloaded apps? If yes then you can right click on app and click on pin option like below.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/kn5wB.png

Comment: No, i want that when a user click on my app that is pinned on the sidebar like shown on your screenshot and gets redirected to a tab which contains the website i want, the tab expands itself to take all the free space in the teams client. (exactly like when you create a tab in teams, then hover over it with your mouse, click on the little arrow and click the "expand tab" option ; this reduces the right panel).

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be any graph API available for pin an App.

We have app related graph API available for add app to team and install app to user.
Ref Doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/team-post-installedapps?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/userteamwork-post-installedapps?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

To redirecting your Tab in application you can use deeplink to Tab of an application.

Reference Document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/build-and-test/deep-link-application?tabs=teamsjs-v2#generate-a-deep-link-to-your-tab